# When creating RAID 1, will content on both disks be deleted?

Tags: raid, raid-1

I set up a RAID1 with two disks on my computer. Then I updated my BIOS and now I don't have the RAID setup any more (I see both drives in Windows).

If I try to set this up again, will I lose the data?

I use Gigabyte GA-Z170-Gaming K3-EU S-1151 ATX motherboard which has "Intel Smart Response Technology" RAID. 
I use NTFS file system.

Comment: hardware or software raid? Do you see the drives as raw drives or something else?

Comment: Hmm... good question. I don't know. The specs says I have "Intel Smart Response Technology" RAID. It's whatever comes with my motherboard which I configure in BIOS. The disks use NTFS file system (not RAW)

Comment: If its running NTFS - might be a good idea to back up our files first!